# Issues loading parameters on a C# RDLC Report

Tags: c#, winforms, report, reporting

Thanks for reading my question. I used to load a report with a button, after selecting dates (from and to), I used mysql and c#, and here are some images so you can look the issues.

Here is the principal issue/error

[image: Error 1]

Here is my Report, as you can see, at the left side, it has the parameters required

[image: Report]

Here i have the dataset/Query to that report, it has the @parameters here too

[image: Query]

Finally, the code for the click event to generate the report

[image: Code]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried this before calling `reportViewer1.RefreshReport()`?

```
 reportViewer1.LocalReport.SetParameters(new ReportParameter[]{
                new ReportParameter("desde",desde.ToShortDateString()),
                new ReportParameter("hasta", hasta.ToShortDateString())
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this on `button1_Click` event:

```
        DateTime desde = dt_desde.Value;
        DateTime haste =dt_hasta.Value;

        this.byc_articulosTableAdapter.Fill(this.datasetResumenInventario.byc_articulos, desde,haste);
        this.reportViewer1.RefreshReport();
```

If u have parameter query for report binding then u must pass those parameters while dataAdaptor filling ( `byc_articulosTableAdapter` ). Hope this helps u.